# C# ASCII GetBytes how to set which character is used for unrecognizable conversion?

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, encoding, ascii

I am porting some code from native C++ to C# and I need to do the following:

`ASCII.GetBytes` when it encounters a unicode character it does not recognize it returns to me character with decimal number 63 (question mark) but in my C++ code using `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, ...` when it encounters a character it doesn't know it uses character with decimal number 37 (% sign).

My question is how can I make ASCII.GetBytes return to me #37 instead of #63 for unknown characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, you can use the `DecoderFallback`/`EncoderFallback` of an encoding to decide how it will behave. You can't change the fallback of `Encoding.ASCII` itself, but you can clone it and then set the fallback. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        Encoding asciiClone = (Encoding) Encoding.ASCII.Clone();
        asciiClone.DecoderFallback = new DecoderReplacementFallback("%");
        asciiClone.EncoderFallback = new EncoderReplacementFallback("%");

        byte[] bytes = { 65, 200, 66 };
        string text = asciiClone.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints A%B
        bytes = asciiClone.GetBytes("A\u00ffB");
        Console.WriteLine(bytes[1]); // Prints 37
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for EncoderFallback thanks! asciiClone.GetBytes("☃").  This is why you are #1 Jon :)

Comment: @Brian: Sorry, I'm not sure why I used DecoderFallback instead of EncoderFallback. Will edit the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the C++ code calls `WideCharToMultiByte` with `lpDefaultChar = "%"`.

There's no way to pass this into the `Encoding.GetBytes` call, but you could call `WideCharToMultiByte` using P/Invoke.

Comment: Unfortunately the C++ strings are in a database and already converted.  So I have millions of these already converted strings from C++ that I need to keep the same moving forward with C#.

Comment: To make matters worse this is an sql injection C# dll not a normal C# dll so I don't think I can p/invoke WideCharToMultiByte.